# How to retrieve Postgresql Sequence-cache value from Postgresql Catalog tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have used this below query to get the complete information of Sequence objects from the Postgresql catalog table

```
select s.sequence_name, s.start_value, s.minimum_value, s.maximum_value, s.increment, s.cycle_option 
from information_schema.sequences s 
 where s.sequence_schema='schema1'
```

One more attribute value am not able to get is "Cache" value.

Am using Postgresql 9.2

Here is the DDL syntax for the sequence with cache,

> ALTER SEQUENCE [ IF EXISTS ] name [ INCREMENT [ BY ] increment ]
>
> [ MINVALUE minvalue | NO MINVALUE ] [ MAXVALUE maxvalue | NO MAXVALUE
>   ]
>
> [ START [ WITH ] start ]
>
> [ RESTART [ [ WITH ] restart ] ]
>
> [ CACHE cache ] [ [ NO ] CYCLE ]
>
> [ OWNED BY { table_name.column_name | NONE } ]

Is there any Postgres functions to get this Sequence cache value ?

Thanks,

Ravi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With PostgreSQL 10** or newer, the cache size can be obtained from the system view [`pg_sequences`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-sequences.html) or the system table [`pg_sequence`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-sequence.html):

```
SELECT cache_size FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequences
 WHERE schemaname='public' and sequencename='s';
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT seqcache FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequence
  WHERE seqrelid = 'public.s'::regclass;
```

Omit the schema qualification (`public` or more generally the name of the schema) in the 2nd query to use automatically `search_path` instead of a fixed schema.

**With versions older than v10**, you may query the sequence itself as if it was a table.

For example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s CACHE 10;
SELECT cache_value FROM s;
```

Result:

```
 cache_value 
-------------
          10
```

Or

```
\x
SELECT * FROM s;
```

Result:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--------------------
sequence_name | s
last_value    | 1
start_value   | 1
increment_by  | 1
max_value     | 9223372036854775807
min_value     | 1
cache_value   | 10
log_cnt       | 0
is_cycled     | f
is_called     | f
```

Comment: This doesn't work in recent versions of Postgres.

Answer (score 5):

This no longer works in Postgres 10.  You can use

```
select seqcache from pg_sequence where seqrelid = 's'::regclass;
```